# For loops in Liquid: using reversed in conjunction with limit:1

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm building a simple blog using Jekyll, and I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out this problem.

The index page of the site is meant to feature a single, most recent article, with the structure looking something like below (pardon the mess):

```
{% for post in site.posts reversed limit:1 %}
    <div class="post">
        <div class="post-inner">
            <h3 class="posttitle"><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
            <p class="postdate">{{ post.date | date: "%d %B %Y" }}</p>
            {{ post.content }}
            <a href="{{ post.url }}#disqus_thread" class="commentLink"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The above template works perfectly fine when the limit is not restrictive (i.e does not exist or is set to the length of the array). It seems to only be when the limit is *actually* restricting the result that the loop ignores reversed.

I've tried clearing the browser cache, which is what got it working without limit:1, but the progress ends there.

Thanks for the help, and I would be happy to provide more detail if this is not enough.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What is Jekyll actually outputting for you?

From what I understand, the reversed filter is applied last. So let assume you posted the first 15 days of Aug, and lets also say you do something like this:

```
{% for post in site.posts limit:5 %}
    {{ post.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

You post array would be ordered in the following pattern

[Aug 15, Aug 14, Aug 13, Aug 12, Aug 11]

And then if you reversed it

```
{% for post in site.posts reversed limit:5 %}
    {{ post.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

You post array would be ordered in the following pattern

[Aug 11, Aug 12, Aug 13, Aug 14, Aug 15]

With all that said, I'm a little perplexed as to why you are not using

```
{% for post in site.posts limit:1 %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. I feel somewhat incompetent, as upon reading your answer I instantly realized what the issue was. All of my test posts happened to be made on a single day. Because the explicit dating in the post.md filenames are accurate only to the day, I'm assuming Jekyll was unable to  (obviously) differentiate between times. Not sure if there is a way around this. However, relating to this question, I just made a new post and it all worked fine. Woops. Thanks again!

Answer (score 16):

Hack to have custom reversed sorting by custom field with limit:

```
{% assign items = site.items | sort: 'some_field' | reverse %}
{% for item in items limit:10 %}
    <li><a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

It's important to assign to some custom var, sort (and reverse) there and only then loop with limit.

Comment: This was sooo helpful! I was trying to work with reversed, while I could've just used the filter from the start. Thnak you!

Comment: When I do this I get an error saying that the stack level is too deep.

Comment: Not working.
' | reverse' needs to be removed from the first line.
Instead there must be an 'reversed' in the second line.